# Storing data in a Node for a BST

Tags: java, arraylist, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a homework assignment where I need to load patient data into a node, then be able to search through the tree. The node will store patient name, doctors name, their current appointment, and there next annual appointment date. The data is read in from a text file. I want to use an arrayList to store the data into the nodes, but the confusing part is how can I store just the certain data of the arrayList into each node? (I hope that makes sense)
This is my class for reading in my text file...(Array implementation isn't complete)

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class readFile {
private Scanner x;


public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("patients.txt"));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't find file!");
    }

}

public void readFile(){

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();   
    while(x.hasNext()){
        String PatientName = x.next();
        String DoctorName = x.next();
        String currentApp = x.next();
        String NextApp = x.next();


    }
}
public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}

}
```

And here is my tree class

```
public class Tree {

    Node root;

    public void addNode(int key, String patientName, String DocName, String currentApp, String nextApp){
        Node newNode = new Node(key, patientName, DocName, currentApp, nextApp);

        if(root == null){
            root = newNode;
        }

        else{
            Node currentNode = root;

            Node parent;

            while(true){
                parent = currentNode;

                if(key < currentNode.key){
                    currentNode = currentNode.leftChild;

                    if(currentNode == null){
                        parent.leftChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    }

                }
                else{
                    currentNode = currentNode.rightChild;

                    if (currentNode ==null){
                        parent.rightChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }


    public void Traversal(Node currentNode){
        if(currentNode != null){
            Traversal(currentNode.leftChild);
            System.out.println(currentNode);

            Traversal(currentNode.rightChild);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Tree binaryTree = new Tree();
        readFile read = new readFile();

        read.openFile();
        read.readFile();

    }
}

class Node{
    int key;
    String patientName;
    String DocName;
    String currentApp;
    String nextApp;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(int key, String patientName, String DocName, String currentApp, String nextApp){

        this.key = key;
        this.patientName = patientName;
        this.DocName = DocName;
        this.currentApp = currentApp;
        this.nextApp = nextApp;


    }



}
```

This is the text file

```
   Baker, William,      Chavez,     04/01/05,   04/10/06
Sanchez, Jose,      Chavez,     06/15/05,
Anderson, Robert,   Wong,       04/02/05,   03/30/06
Watson, David,      Chavez,     05/03/05,   04/28/06
Chung, Yu,      Gilbert,    07/10/05,
Griffin, Sandy,     Gilbert,    06/20/05,   06/20/06
Marcus, Wendy,      Wong,       08/02/05,   08/03/06
Williams, Rebbeca,  Chavez,     08/10/05,   08/11/06
Kennedy, Fred,      Wong,       07/16/05,   07/15/06
Henderson, Paul,    Wong,       02/15/05,           
Tucker, Matthew,    Wong,       04/10/05,   04/11/06
Coombs, Jean,       Gilbert,    05/01/05,   04/10/06    
Earl, Gary,     Gilbert,    06/03/05,   05/10/06
Atkins, Anthony,    Chavez,     09/10/05,   09/11/06
Garcia, Jesus,      Chavez,     10/10/05,   
David, James,       Wong,       02/02/05,   02/03/06
Young, Ed,      Gilbert,    07/09/05,   07/10/06
Jones, Richard,     Gilbert,    08/01/05,   08/10/06
Peterson, Jerry,    Wong,       06/02/05,   06/03/06
Arnold, Belinda,    Chavez,     01/10/05,   01/11/06
Franklin, Jason,    Wong,       09/12/05,   09/13/06
Trent, Joseph,      Gilbert,    03/12/05,   
Valdez, Tomas,      Gilbert,    10/15/05,   10/10/06
Gent, Charles,      Wong,       10/22/05,   10/11/06
Roper, Joan,        Chavez,     03/10/05,   03/21/06
Lopez, Ricky,       Wong,       03/24/05,   03/25/06
Henry, Sarah,       Gilbert,    04/18/05,   04/17/06
Nathan, James,      Chavez,     06/10/05,   08/11/06
Ulvan, Rachel,      Chavez,     09/10/05,   
Mears, Sally,       Wong,       05/05/05,   
Edwards, Sam,       Gilbert,    05/21/05,   05/22/06
Rubino, Ian,        Gilbert,    07/24/05,   07/21/06
Osborn, Janet,      Chavez,     07/10/05,   07/11/06
Barton, Michael,    Chavez,     10/10/05,   10/16/06
Quinn, Pat,     Gilbert,    08/27/05,   08/29/06
Inglis, Peggy,      Wong,       08/30/05,   08/29/06
```

Comment: You create the patient `Node` and use setters and getters to set and get the data you need. Or you can have different patient `Node` constructors where you pass in only the arguments you need.

Comment: @ceelos thanks for the suggestions, Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class named `Appointment`. Store it both in your node and `ArrayList`.

```
class Appointment {
    String patientName;
    String DocName;
    String currentApp;
    String nextApp;

    public Appointment (/*Get parameters*/) {
         /*Set parameters to members*/
    }
}
```

So  this is your new `Node`

```
class Node{
    int key;
    Appointment app;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(int key, Appointment app){
        this.key = key;
        this.app = app;
    }

}
```

And you can define an `ArrayList` like that: `ArrayList<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Ahhhhh, I never thought about storing the array into something else! Awesome